# Gwt-ext window positioning

Tags: window, gwt-ext

How do I make an instance of gwtext.client.widgets.Window  appear at specific DIV in my html ? I tried window.anchorTo(DOM.getElementById("Some_Div"),"left", new int[]{0,0}), thinking the window will anchor itself to div id="Some_Div"   in my html. it didnt.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the gwt-ext library in a couple of months, but you might want to try this if you haven't already. It *should* attach the widget where you want it. That said, there are some cases where the gwt-ext widgets react in ways that are not intuitive to someone who really understands the normal GWT widgets.

```
RootPanel.get("Some_Div_Id").add( someWidget )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
window.alignTo(DOM.getElementById("Some_Div"),"tl-tl", new int[]{0,0});
```

for positioning the window's top left to Some_Div's top left corner.

These are the valid strings for position argument:

```
Value  Description
-----  -----------------------------
tl     The top left corner (default)
t      The center of the top edge
tr     The top right corner
l      The center of the left edge
c      In the center of the element
r      The center of the right edge
bl     The bottom left corner
b      The center of the bottom edge
br     The bottom right corner
```

Refer the Ext documentation for detailed explanation.